# Trouble with ExpressJS routing

Tags: express, routes

I'm trying to move the auth workflow into a separate router file

I have the following app.js:

```
...
var index = require('./routes/index');
var auth = require('./routes/auth');

var app = express();
...
app.use('/', index);
app.use('/auth', auth);
...
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

and the following routes/auth.js:

```
router.get('signin', function(req, res){
  // this gets called at localhost:3000/signin
})

router.get('google/callback:code', function(req, res, next){
  // this produces a not found error at localhost:3000/auth/google/callback
});
```

The 404 error occurs when I call `/auth/google/callback?code=...`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?code=` is a [query string](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query) and not a part of the route. You can therefore remove `:code` from the route:

```
router.get('/google/callback', function(req, res, next){

});
```

You can access the code inside the function like this:

```
router.get('/google/callback', function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.query.code);
});
```